# Can I document a virtual member in a derived class without overriding it?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Say I have some external library with an undocumented base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void func() { /* something */ }
}
```

In my library, I want to derive from this class, and document all the members:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    /*!
        @brief do a thing
    */
    void other_func();

    /*!
        @brief do the base thing and another thing
    */
    void func(int arg);

    /*!
        @brief do the baseclass thing

        Also, guarantee some extra invariants XYZ that the baseclass
        does, but does not require subclassers to do.
    */
    using Base::func;
    // virtual void func() override;
    // don't want to declare a new implementation of func() here
    // so how can I attach a docstring to func() such that doxygen picks up on it?
}
```

How can I document the inherited `Base::func` in `Derived.h`?

Comment: Of course, you can add a comment, but the whole idea of virtual member functions is that you do NOT have to declare them if you don't override it. And if your new class does NOT override it, then why should you have/need a docstring there? It does the same thing that the base-class does - which hopefully has been documented? If not, add documentation to that, and post the patch as feedback to the original vendor/author!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The issue is that it hasn't been documented in the external base class, so I want to add documentation inside my library for clarity, that will be picked up by doxygen. Also, there are some extra invariants that Derived::func is expected to meet, that I would like to document - it just so happens that `Base::func` already meets these by coincidence, so no reimplementation is necessary

Answer (score 3):

Use the @fn tag. You use that tag and specify the function signature then the remainder of that block will be assigned to that function.

Sorry I'd give an example but on phone.

And I'd link to the official docs but frustratingly, and somewhat ironically, doxygen's reference web site does not work on mobile. So just google for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my actual case doesn't work with this - I have an overload of the inherited name, and all attempts to use `\fn func()` are just adding the documentation to `func(int)`. I've updated my question to reflect this